# Custom Uppy Plugin

Tags: javascript, reactjs, plugins

I'm trying to make a custom Uppy React plugin but I'm getting the following error

'TypeError: Cannot call a class as a function'

```
import Plugin from 'uppy/src/core/Plugin';

export default class DropZone extends Plugin {
}
```

I am then consuming the component as follows:

```
import React from 'react';
import Uppy from 'uppy/lib/core/Core';
import DropZone from '../DropZone';

const uppy = new Uppy({ debug: true });
uppy.run();

export default class FileManager extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (<DropZone uppy={uppy} />);
  }
}
```

I've cut down the code for simplicity.  I looked at the implementation of the uppy DragDrop plugin and followed its implement but still get the same error.

Has anyone had experience writing a react plugin for Uppy? as I'm lost as to how I can resolve this error.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've successfully created a plugin using the following import statement:

```
import { Uppy, Plugin, PluginOptions, UppyFile } from "@uppy/core";
```

It's not clear from your question whether you're using the npm package or have downloaded manually, but in my case I installed Uppy using:

```
npm i @uppy/core
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, in your "DropZone" plugin, you'll need to implement at least the install() and uninstall() methods (those get called by uppy).

Second, if you want to tell uppy to use your plugin, you need to do something like:

`const uppy = 
   new Uppy({ debug: true })
   .use(DropZone)
   .run();`

I suggest simply [looking at the source code for other plugins](https://github.com/transloadit/uppy/blob/master/packages/%40uppy/form/src/index.js) to understand how they work, there are different kinds of Plugins - Providers for files management, GUI plugins for display in the Dashboard, etc...

Hope this helps